# Selecting the highest number between two elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have multiple 2-D arrays as defined below:

`a=[[4,6],[7,8],[9,10]]`

I want to create a separate array(1-D) that takes the maximum number between the two elements in the array above. The solution should look like the below:

`a=[6,8,10]`

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: The best way to learn is to play different syntax and `methods` - not to post your question w/o any attempts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple list comprehension for this:

```
a = [[4,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
b = [max(elem) for elem in a]
```

Comment: I tried, but I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-290de65ff8bb> in <module>
----> 1 b = [max(elem) for elem in y_pred]
      2 print(b)

<ipython-input-64-290de65ff8bb> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 b = [max(elem) for elem in y_pred]
      2 print(b)

TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and take the `max` value of each entry in the outer list.

```
a = [[4, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
result = [max(entry) for entry in a]
print(result)
```

This will give you `[6, 8, 10]`.

Comment: Hi Matthias,

Below is my actual dataset:
[2.90282569e-05, 9.99935508e-01], [2.84539819e-01, 8.28208566e-01]], dtype=float32)
I wanted to take the maximum of the two elements in the array and create a separate array(1-D) for the new values:
I tried but I get the following error message:
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-64-290de65ff8bb> in <module> ----> 1 b = [max(elem) for elem in y_pred] 2 print(b) <ipython-input-64-290de65ff8bb> in <listcomp>(.0) ----> 1 b = [max(elem) for elem in y_pred] 2 print(b) TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable

Comment: So you don't have the list you showed in your question, but a `numpy` array. You might want to ask a new question and mention this fact.